# How to create a stack for UIImageview and push the image view on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, stack

Well I'm developing drawing application and I want to create a undo option in it so thought of creating a stack and pushing the `UIImageview` on top of the stack .

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840#comments) .

Comment: You might want to think about saving path definitions rather than (potentially thousands of) complete images.

Comment: How to do that , as I'm new to IOS , Can u help me out.

Comment: You could save an array of bezier paths. On undo you would need to redraw them all to recreate the image...

Comment: Can send we the snippet of code , so that i can modify it.
i have posted the tutorial link above.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you create and immediately render each drawn path into the context. This means the only thing you have is an 'image' of the current result. You don't have any history.

Storing the history as an actual exported image from the context after each edit will take a lot of disk space (though it will be fast). If you want to allow only a handful of undo steps then it could be an option. Store the images to disk. Keep a frame count and use that to create the file names. Delete the oldest file when adding new ones. Undo by deleting the newest file and drawing the saved image into the context.

If you want to allow more undo steps, you need to save the delats (each path drawn). This can be an array of `UIBezierPath`s (created with [`bezierPathWithCGPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithCGPath%3a)). To undo, delete the last array element and redraw the context by iterating through the paths.